# How to add default values in a form using flask?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2

I am trying to add the name of the current user as default into the database after the user submits a form. Currently, I am passing the value to an input value and users can delete it not linking the post to its account/user.

```
 {% if session['email'] != None %}
            <!--seller name-->
            <input type="text" id="seller" name="seller" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Seller Name" value="{{session['name']}}"> 
            {% endif %}
```

```
@app.route('/insert_product', methods=['POST'])
def insert_product():
    products=mongo.db.products
    if request.method == 'POST':
        products.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())
    return redirect(url_for('user'))
```

What I want is simply that users don't need to put their name, rather their name based on their session be added by default into the form as `'seller':session['name']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always override `seller` field with value from session before inserting values to the database.

```
@app.route('/insert_product', methods=['POST'])
def insert_product():
    products=mongo.db.products
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_dict = request.form.to_dict()
        form_dict.update({'seller': session['name']})
        products.insert_one(form_dict)
    return redirect(url_for('user'))
```